# Calling method from an instance of a class

Tags: java, methods

I'm new at java so sorry for the inconsistencies.

I'm creating a library program and I'm having trouble calling a method from the Book class in the Patron class.

In the Patron class I have a method checkOutBook() which a user can input a book to check out. However I'm having trouble accessing the setStatus() method in Book. I know I have to call it against an instance of the Book class but I'm unsure how to do so with a user inputed string.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book implements BookInterface {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  static ArrayList < String > UserList = new ArrayList < String > ();
  static ArrayList < String > BookList = new ArrayList < String > ();

  public String title;
  public String author;
  public Book book;
  private String status;
  private String borrower;

  public Book(String t, String a) {
    title = t;
    author = a;
  }

  //constructor create new book
  public Book(String newTitle) {
    title = newTitle;
  }


  public String toString() {
    return title + " " + author;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
  }

  public String getStatus(String book) {
    return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public void setBorrower(String borrower) {
    this.borrower = borrower;
  }

  public String getBorrower(String checkPatron) {
    return borrower;
  }

  public String getBook(String checkPatron) {
    return book;
  }

  public void setBook(Book bookCheckOut) {
    this.book = bookCheckOut;
  }


}
```

```java
public void CheckOutBook() {
    Scanner inputread = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter full patron name: ");
    String borrower = inputread.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter book title to check out: ");
    String bookCheckOut = inputread.nextLine();

    if (Book.BookList.contains(bookCheckOut)) {
      Book.BookList.remove(bookCheckOut);
      Book.setStatus("OUT");      //error message        
      Book.setBorrower(borrower);  //error message 
      System.out.println("----------" + bookCheckOut + " has been checked out!----------");
      System.out.println("-------------------BOOK STATUS:---------------------");
      System.out.println("Book Title: " + bookCheckOut);
      System.out.println("Book Status: Checked out");
      System.out.println("Borrower: " + borrower);
      System.out.println("Due Date: " + dueDate);
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
```

I attempted to do this but it didn't work either :(
Thank you for your help!

```java
Book bookCheckOut = new Book(bookCheckOut);  //error: constructor Book(book) undefined
bookCheckOut.setStatus("OUT");
bookCheckOut.setBorrower(borrower);
bookCheckOut.setBook(bookCheckOut);
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript, thus the code snippets are ineffective in this case

Comment: Book bookCheckOut = new Book(bookCheckOut);   <- what is this? try this -> "Book bookCheckOut = new Book("bookname");" or ""Book bookCheckOut = new Book("title", "author");". Remember that using a same variable name to different type of variable is danger.

Comment: what are you trying to do? What is the output you want to see and what is the output you are currently getting? It would help if you posted your full program.

Comment: @ThisClark hi! sorry about that I wasn't aware as I new to all of this but thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @KitFung thank you!!! Would I still be able to create an instance of the Book class with a string user input? I attempted to do so but confused, as bookCheckOut is the string variable for whatever title the user wanted to check out. If "b" was the name of the instance would it be something like `Book b = new Book("bookCheckOut")` or `new Book(bookCheckOut)` ?

Comment: yes, it is ok. Just make sure no repeating variable name and ensure the input is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Book bookCheckOut = new Book(bookCheckOut); <~ I think you are getting confused because you already defined bookCheckOut as a String from the scanner and in this line you are setting it to a book object. Try changing the first bookCheckOut in this line to something else. Syntax: Book bookObjectName = new Book("String");

For the setStatus and setBorrower error you are trying to use those methods as if they were static. To fix this don't call Book.setStatus but replace Book with your instantiated book object name. Example: Book b = new Book ("Asd","abc"); b.setStatus("xyz");

Also, why do have two scanners?

Comment: P.S. This is very similar to a question on got on an AP Computer Science A AP practice test. Also, I am currently typing this on my phone so I am able to post a corrected version of your code. If my answer was not sufficient and a better answer has not been posted by tomorrow I will append a corrected version of your code to my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Hi! Thank you!! I was originally trying to do this but I got thrown off because the program prompts the user to enter any book title they want to check out and I was unsure of how to create an instance of the book class with a user inputed string. For example if "bookTitle" was used as the String variable that the user enters  would it be something like 'Book bookCheckOut = new Book(bookTitle)' ?  or 'Book bookCheckOut = new Book("bookTitle")' ?

Comment: If you have a String that already holds the title (Like so: String bookTitle = "A great book title";) then you would use Book bookCheckOut = new Book(bookTitle); This would create a Book Object 'bookCheckOut' with the title 'A great book title'.

Comment: If this was the answer you were  looking for then don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one, but if you still are confused please ask more questions!

Answer (score 0):

Change `Book.BookList` from `ArrayList<String>` to `Map<String, Book>` as shown below:

```
public class Book {

  static Map<String, Book> BookList = new HashMap<>();

  ...
```

Then in `CheckOutBook()` change:

```
if (Book.BookList.contains(bookCheckOut)) {
  Book.BookList.remove(bookCheckOut);
  Book.setStatus("OUT");      //error message        
  Book.setBorrower(borrower);  //error message 

  ...
```

To:

```
Book book = Book.BookList.get(bookCheckOut);
if (book != null) {
  Book.BookList.remove(bookCheckOut);
  book.setStatus("OUT");     
  book.setBorrower(borrower);

  ...
```